# How would I go about generating this sort of fractal?

Tags: fractals

Don't really know if this question belongs here or on stack overflow, so sorry if this is not the right place. I have picture of this fractal:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsVRs.png]

I have not seen this fractal among other more popular fractals. I don't know if this is a valid fractal. How would I go about generating this sort of fractal?

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to the the [Viscek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicsek_fractal) fractal.

I have a feeling like they are equal, but I can't prove it from the top of my head. The edges on the NW/SW/SE/NE side don't really contribute to the recursion, so they should be equal at the limit.

Information about generating the Viscek fractal and some basic properties can be found on the wikipedia page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicsek_fractal .

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing, but how I should go about these corners? I'm using a subtraction approach on generating plain Vicsek fractal and I can't really imagine how I would keep these corners and not mess up the whole image

Answer (score 2):

You can use an L-system to generate the fractal. `F` denotes move forward one unit, `+` rotate left 90 degrees, `-` rotate right 90 degrees.

**Level 0** 
starting from top of leftmost edge pointing east

```
F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F-
=:
L(0) -F-
```

**Level 1** 
starting from 1/3 of the way down the rightmost edge of the center square (1/3 size) pointing east

```
F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F +F-F+
F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F +F-F+
F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F +F-F+
F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F -F- F+F-F+F +F-F+
=
L(0) +F-F+ L(0) +F-F+ L(0) +F-F+ L(0) +F-F+
=:
L(1) +F-F+
```

**Level 2** 
starting from 1/3 of the way down the rightmost edge of the center square (1/7 size) pointing east

```
L(1) +F-F+ L(1) +F-F+ L(1) +F-F+ L(1) +F-F+
=:
L(2) +F-F+
```

**Level 3** and beyond, similarly

```
L(n) +F-F+ L(n) +F-F+ L(n) +F-F+ L(n) +F-F+
=:
L(n+1) +F-F+
```

Comment: How do you read these? I mean what are the rules and what is the axiom?

Comment: I suppose the rule is `L => L +F-F+ L +F-F+ L +F-F+ L` and the seed/axiom is `S => L +F-F+`